# gtk-recordmydesktop is not working anymore in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gtk, recordmydesktop

I was recording my screen through gtk-recordmydesktop and it crashed during the mid recording, I have relaunched the application through command line.But it came with the error. See the following error code:

```
#gtk-recordmydesktop 
Gtk-Message: 20:26:49.852: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/gtk-recordmydesktop", line 43, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/bin/gtk-recordmydesktop", line 40, in main
tr=rmdSimple.simpleWidget()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/recordMyDesktop/rmdSimple.py", line                   509, in __init__
self.__subWidgets__()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/recordMyDesktop/rmdSimple.py", line   88, in __subWidgets__
self.image=sT.GtkThumbSelector(self,self.values[5],self.hidden,2000)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/recordMyDesktop/rmdSelectThumb.py",  line 69, in __init__
self.__subsample__(sroot,self.wwidth,self.wheight,self.root,self.factor)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/recordMyDesktop/rmdSelectThumb.py", line 79, in __subsample__
im2.put_pixel(k/stride,i/stride,im1.get_pixel(k,i))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_pixel'
```

I have tried to removed the gtk-recordmydesktop and again reinstalled it, but the efforts got no fruits, The commands I have used are :

```
#sudo apt remove gtk-recordmydesktop --purge
#sudo apt-get clean
#sudo apt install gtk-recordmydesktop
#gtk-recordmydesktop
```

meanwhile my system specifications are:
OS = Linux, Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Output of the `uname -a` shows:

```
Linux suryaveer 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: And 20.04 doesn't have a pacakge anymore even: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gtk-recordmydesktop&searchon=names | https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236345/20-04-cant-install-gtk-recordmydesktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like last release of `gtk-recordmydesktop` was made in 2008. You may want to try out SimpleScreenRecorder that seems to offer similar easy to use interface.

You can install it with this command

```
sudo apt install simplescreenrecorder
```

https://sourceforge.net/projects/recordmydesktop/files/gtk-recordMyDesktop/

http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/

Comment: Ubuntu 18.0.1 user here, had same issue `Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"` with already installed `simplescreenrecorder`. I had to remove and reinstall it, then it worked again.