# 20.04: Can't install gtk-recordmydesktop

Tags: apt, 20.04, recordmydesktop

I want to use [recordmydesktop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/recordmydesktop.1.html) in Ubuntu 20.04, and installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop
```

But when I want to record, by command `recordmydesktop` it records full screen and save it in the home. But I don't want this. I need to tell recordmydesktop to record an ara or window to record. not full screen. and it's so hard to do this by command line!! I searched in google and I just saw this command. But it doesn't work.

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop
```

and give me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gtk-recordmydesktop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gtk-recordmydesktop' has no installation candidate
```

I use ubuntu 20.04. What should I do??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is installable by using packages from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gtk-recordmydesktop/gtk-recordmydesktop_0.3.8-4.1ubuntu1_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./gtk-recordmydesktop_0.3.8-4.1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Comment: it seams `gtk-recordmydesktop` have some issues on 20.04, the UI window just disappears as soon a I start recording.

Comment: I also had this issue. I solved it by adding a notification area indicator to the GNOME top panel. `gtk-recordmydesktop` puts an icon there that you can click to stop recording. Without the indicator added to the top panel, the icon is not visible. At least it works so on GNOME Flashback desktop. I don't know how is it on regular GNOME Shell desktop.

Comment: to stop record run "killall recordmydesktop"

Answer (score 21):

It is because of it is obsoleted and currently not supported. You could install it by enabling some older repository (`deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main universe` for example) which contain it or download its packages from there. Enabling other ubuntu version repository should be immediately disabled just after installing. But it is a bad way which could break your system. Better use newer supported software.

Vokoscreen records a desktop, a window and an area:

```
sudo apt install vokoscreen
```

[image]

Or use vokoscreenNG:

```
sudo apt install vokoscreen-ng
```

[image]

Comment: a better version of vokoscreen is: vokoscreenNG

Comment: Alternatives are discussed extensively at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-can-i-record-my-screen BTW.

Comment: In the audio section it says *"Audio recording not implemente"*

Answer (score 9):

Ignore this if you got gtk-recordmydesktop to work. I only add an alternative in case someone of you could not.

A solution that works well for me is the light-weight simple screen recorder. It is in the Ubuntu-repositories and can be installed the usual way,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install simplescreenrecorder
```

There is also a 32 bit OpenGL version that works on 64 bit systems. More information for this screen recorder can be found here: https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/#download

Comment: This seems to support more codecs than vokoscreenNG, and also supports the view following cursor.

Comment: Yeah, this tool works pretty well, I've tested it with recording the screen area, mp4 Video / mp3 audio, speakers, and mic as a built-in device, works brilliantly! Thanks!

Comment: When I try to start it, I get the error: <
***You are using a non-X11 window system (e.g. Wayland) which is currently not supported by SimpleScreenRecorder. Several features will most likely not work properly. In order to solve this, you should log out, choose a X11/Xorg session at the login screen, and then log back in.***